# Cloning a USB stick

Tags: backup, usb-drive, dd

make a dd backup of the dm-crypt usb and rest the test the backup

I know I can make a copy of a usb stick using the following

> sudo dd if=/dev/sdb of=~/USB_image

and then restore it using

> sudo dd if=~/USB_image of=/dev/sdb

My question is, is it possible to get rid of the image step or pipe the copy directoy from 1 usb to another?  So basically, to copy directly from 1 usb stick to another.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use:

```
sudo dd if=/dev/sdX of=/dev/sdY
```

to copy the contents of `/dev/sdX` to `/dev/sdY`.

Comment: Just check the devices first, because usually /dev/sda is the hardrive where the system is installed, so this command token literally might end into a dissaster.

Comment: I will **strongly** advise to use generic names in these kind of answers, like `/dev/sdX` and `/dev/sdY`. Much better have a `device not found` error than wiping your disk... and if the user does not know how to substitute them with real names, he or she should **never** use commands that starts with `sudo dd`.